# How to send 2 emails in a single thread through Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to send 2 emails to the same person through Logic Apps (Office 365 Connector). Both the emails should be visible in the same thread.

When I am using **Send an email(V2)**, it sends in a different thread.

I cannot use **Reply to email (V3)**, because when I send the email I do not get Message Id. This I can use only when I receive a email and then I reply to the same thread.

But I want to send 2 or more emails without getting an reply also in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using 2 logic apps where one of the logic apps will send the mail and the other will be triggered as soon as the message arrives in the inbox and replies to that particular email.

**Flow of Logic App 1:**

[image]

**Flow of Logic App 2:**

[image]

As there might be a possibility of Logic App going into the loop, I'm using condition. Likewise, you can use your own logic.

**Results:**

[image]